# Можно ли изображение для карточки товара Woocommerce вставить через html/css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Извиняюсь за крайне тупой вопрос, но все мои попытки не увенчались успехом. 
как я понял за изображения всех карточек отвечает файл **/woocommerce/template/single-product/product-image.php.**
Пытался через селектор определенного товара сделать так (в файле woocommerce.css):

```
#blog > div.container.rsrc-container > div.row.rsrc-fullwidth-home > div.rsrc-home > div > div > div > ul > li {
    background-image: url ('../assets/css/3.gif');

}
```

Подскажите направление пожалуйста, у меня идея заключается чтобы вставить **.gif** изображение которое будет запускаться только при наведении курсора мышки (посредством замены статического изображения на **.gif** через свойство **visibility**)

Comment: Что за ересь? За изображение карточки товара "отвечает" то изображение которое ты задашь товару в админке. И другие изображений товара для галереи там же.

Comment: все верно, вот именно за "то изображение которое ты задашь товару в админке" и отвечает **product-image.php**, а мне надо на отдельный товар повесить два изображения, одно статическое, другое динамическое через html/css.

Comment: Что значит "динамическое" и почему через css?

Comment: динамическое то бишь **.gif** (анимация), но чтобы изначально показывалось статическое изображение (т.е первый кадр этого **.gif**), а сам **.gif** должен появлятся тогда когда наводим на изображение мышкой **(:hover)**, в то же время должно скрываться статическое изображение с помощью **visibility:hidden**, есть варианты как это реализовать, либо обойти другим способом?

Comment: @user271244 все зависит от верстки, при наведении на некий блок, в котором находится картинка, скрывать изображение, а блоку ставить задний фон

Comment: DaemonHK, да, именно так я это и представляю, проблема в том как это провернуть с карточками Woocommerce

Comment: Вообще делать графику товара гиф-анимацией - плохая  идея в принципе. Но что мешает одну из картинок в галере сделать гифкой? А что до css - есть псевдокласс  hover. Можно с его помощью выводить др картинку. Вот только что бы показывало одну из галерейных (или иначе заданных в админке) нужную - тут уже нужно покодить.

Comment: SeVlad, спасибо за вариант, можно и в эту сторону подумать